# Azure B2C authentication for external contacts

Tags: azure, authentication, external, saml, azure-ad-b2c

I've got an application hosted by 3rd party and the goal to grant access for this app from other sources than our Azure tenant. I added my personal account into Azure AD for test and the MS login works fine but the application show an authentication issue. With a discussion of the vendor we figured out that the name (myprivateaccount@mydomain.ie) is different than the nameid match in azure (myprivateaccount_mydomain.ie@myazuretennant.onmicrosoft.com).
Is there any easy way to fix it in the Azure side? Which work even the user name or user's domain have _ in the name/domain as well?

Regards,
Tamas

Comment: You shouldn't be using the user principal name for authorization typically. It can change and in cases where you are added as an external user, you get oddities like this one :/

Comment: What is the authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you add your personal account into Azure AD, this account will be recognized as a guest user(external user). This personal account will be able to login in your application under your tenant.

And like @juunas said, you shouldn't use the user principal name for authorization.